# Google Analytics-BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Is is possible to load the data which is on the Google Analytics Dashboard to BigQuery and then maybe run some queries and export it.
I know that there is an option for exporting the data from big query but the issue that I am facing right now accessing my dashboard data in BigQuery. Any insight into this would be really helpful.

Comment: AFAIK this only works with the rather costly Google Analytics Premium.

Comment: Yes. It does but how is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set up BigQuery for Analytics without assistance. To start you need to contact your Premium support manager https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618 and give him two bits of information:

- BigQuery project ID that should receive your data
- Google Analytics view ID

Your Google Analytics account can handle multiple properties and each property can have more than one view. A view is a subset of the data (defined by custom filters) collected for a single property. By default, every property has a single view that contains all the data for the property. Currently Google Analytics supports only exporting a single view per property to BigQuery, so most likely you want to have this unfiltered view pushed into BigQuery because then you can run queries over all the data for your property. When you submit this request, you will be instructed to modify the ACL of your project so that Google Analytics can write data to your project. Specifically, you will be asked
to add edit permissions on the project for the account: `analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com`

After you have done this, support updates your account configuration so that a nightly job pushes your data into the project. A dataset will be created with a name equal to the view ID you specified in the request, and within that dataset a daily table will be created some time after the end of the day. The tables have the following naming pattern:`ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD`

**Fortunately**, **you can experiment with this feature without going through all this setup or even signing up for a Premium account**. The Google Analytics team provides a sample dataset that you can use to understand the nature of the data generated. You can add this data to your view in the BigQuery UI by adding the project `google.com:analytics-bigquery` using the project menu (the drop-down next to the project name, Switch to Project ➪ Display Project). Alternately, you can navigate to the BigQuery UI link https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/project/google.com:analytics-bigquery
After you add the project, the sample dataset (LondonCycleHelmet) appears in the navigation panel. It contains two tables:

- ga_sessions_20130910
- refunds_201309

For now you can ignore the second table. The first table is the sample table that contains data that corresponds to what Google Analytics collects when users interact with a web property. Selecting the table displays a complicated schema that has a large number of fields

Answer (score 2):

This is only available for Google Analytics Premium customers.   If you are a contact your Google Analytics Premium Account Manager to learn how you can set up BigQuery. You cannot set up BigQuery for Analytics without assistance.

[BigQuery Export for Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en)